# Symfony & doctrine - return json encoded object with extra property and properly encoded DateTime

Tags: php, json, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am sorry for the title being so non-descriptive but the question I am asking is way to broad to fit in 10 words.

I have an Entity called Offlicence.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="offlicences")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Boozator\LocatorBundle\Entity\Repository\OfflicenceRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Offlicence
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $address;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $postcode;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $phone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $notes;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $latitude;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $longitude;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $created;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $updated;
```

I also have an OfflicenceRepostitory with a method of getNearest()

```
public function getNearest($address)
{
    //geocode the address
    $location = $this->geocode($address);
    if(!$location)
    {
        return false;
    }

    $latitude = $location[self::LATITUDE_TAG];
    $longitude = $location[self::LONGITUDE_TAG];

     return $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
                ->select('o')
    //3960 for miles & 6371 for kilometers
                ->addSelect("(6371 * ACOS(SIN(RADIANS($latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(o.latitude)) + COS(RADIANS($latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(o.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(o.longitude) - RADIANS($longitude)))) as distance")
                ->having("distance < 5")
                ->orderBy("distance")
                ->getQuery()    
                ->getResult();
}
```

And the controller that gets a list of shops

```
public function getNearbyAction($address)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getEntityManager();


    $locator = $em->getRepository('BoozatorLocatorBundle:Offlicence');
    $shops = $locator->getNearest($address);

    $ret = json_encode($shops);

    return new Response($ret, 200, array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));//make sure it has the correct content type
}
```

As a result I am getting json encoded array of 2 elements: the array representation of the object (although DateTime objects are dodgy) and a distance.

I am trying to find a cleanest way to return an array of all details and distance as one element, merged. Ideally I'd like to add a new property "distance" to the Offlicence so that it is populated by the query but does not have a corresponding column in a database. I am also trying to json_encode the data I am getting but DateTime objects are converted into another ugly looking array. Can you please tell me what to look at as I am new to Symfony and it's endless world of helpers and extensions?